# How do I draw a set of locate points on a custom map?

Tags: php, mysql

[image]

I have a set of points and a custom map (I made it myself), suppose i want to draw a map like the picture above with a number of points, how can I do that ? Which tool (or language) should i use? How can get those path (which painted red and blue) on my map? 
Thank you :D

Comment: You can use php and the gd2 extension to generate map like that. Or any graphical software ...

Comment: Thank you Spin0us, but can you give me more details. To be honest I'm a newbie in php :D